# How pass a array and setArray in value of provider (React, Typescript, Context)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

How can I pass an array and setArray in value of provider?
My main problem is how to create an interface for this, because it says incorrect type.

The Array contains objects List and I need consult this Array and set to use a filter later.

```
import React from "react";

interface Lista {
  nome: string,
  empresa: string,
  ramal: number
}

const listaInicial: Lista = {
  nome: "",
  empresa: "",
  ramal: 0
}

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const ListaContext = React.createContext<Lista>(listaInicial);

export default function ListaProvider({children}: Props) {
  const [lista, setLista] = React.useState<Lista[]>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLista([
      {
        nome: "nome 1",
        empresa: "matriz",
        ramal: 2000
      },
      {
        nome: "nome 2",
        empresa: "matriz",
        ramal: 2001
      },
      {
        nome: "nome 3",
        empresa: "sede",
        ramal: 2002
      },
      {
        nome: "nome 4",
        empresa: "sede",
        ramal: 2002
      },
    ])
  }, []);

  return (
    <ListaContext.Provider value={{lista, setLista}}>
      {children}
    </ListaContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to create a different interface for React.createContext**

**For example:**

```
    interface ListaContextValue {
     lista:Lista[],
     setLista:(data:Lista[]) => void
    }

    const listaInicial: ListaContextValue = {
      lista:[
       {nome: "",
        empresa: "",
        ramal: 0
       }],
      setLista: (data) => {}
    }
```

And then,

```
const ListaContext = React.createContext<ListaContextValue>(listaInicial);
```

Answer (score 1):

`React.createContext<Lista>(listaInicial);` mean the return value of `ListaContext.Provider`is  `Lista` type.
If you want to set value of provide is `lista` and `setLista` you can try this to not defined the type for `createContext`.

```
const ListaContext = React.createContext(listaInicial);
```

Or

```
const ListaContext = React.createContext<{lista: Lista[], setLista:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Lista[]>> }>(listaInicial);
```